# Does Google Appscript running as Web App contributes to the Total trigger runtime quota?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have created a UI Page with Google Apps Script, it fetches data from a spreadsheet and display it in the Page. A function (added in JS Page) is called at a certain time interval continuously to refresh the content in the Page with the help of JavaScript method "*setInterval(functionName,Time)*". No other triggers are set for this refresh thing.

When I see the executions, the refresh things runs as a web app only.
[image: executions]

Is the web App running time included in the total trigger run-time quota for apps script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `doGet(e)` and `doPost(e)` functions are sometimes referred to as triggers in the documentation so I believe using Web Apps do count towards your trigger quotas. They also count towards your script usage quotas as well.

Comment: Is there any reference document for this?

Comment: `doGet(e)` and `doPost(e)` are listed as triggers in the documentation. See following link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Answer (score 0):

You can run the script for 6 minutes on each execution, for daily executions time there is no reference but you might reach the limitation of triggers total runtime which is 90 min / day

To check other limitations please see: [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas)

Comment: We can run the script manually even if total trigger run time quota is reached. It is a bit confusing

Comment: No, once you reach a limit, whatever limit it is, you can't run it again that day.